# Why is the sign of the tangential component of acceleration negative in this problem?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

[image]
[image]

Since the train is slowing down at a constant velocity, shouldn't the acceleration equal **zero**? Why is it negative in this case?

Comment: It tells you the answer. It decelerated from 87 to 39. Negative acceleration. This is really pretty basic for high school physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't say the train "is slowing down at a constant velocity." That doesn't even make sense --- either it's slowing down, and the velocity is not constant, or it's not slowing down, and the velocity is constant. It can't be both accelerating and at a constant velocity, since the very definition of acceleration is change in velocity with respect to time.

Imagine you are driving in your car, dead north, which we'll call the positive direction. If you slam on the brakes, which direction will the acceleration be in? Since the car is slowing down, your acceleration will be in the South/negative direction. **The brakes are decreasing the car's velocity, which is the same thing as increasing it in the negative direction. Thus the sign of acceleration is negative.**

However, if you have pushed the accelerator to the floor, that would be a positive acceleration, since it is accelerating your car in its direction of positive velocity.

The same concept is true of the train here. Since it is slowing down over some frame of time, and it is moving in the positive direction, the acceleration will be negative. Since we're talking about tangential components, the fact that the train is in rotational motion isn't even relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Problem statement says "the train slows down at constant rate", not "at constant velocity" - in fact, if velocity were constant the train wouldn't be slowing. What the statement means is that the train is slowing with a constant acceleration - at least, the tangential component of acceleration is constant.

Since velocity is decreasing, the sign of the tangential component of acceleration is opposite to the sign of velocity, and the since statement told us to take as positive the direction in which the train is moving (e.g. the direction of velocity), the opposite is the negative direction.

In a more general way, if something is moving in the positive direction, acceleration is positive whenever it's getting faster and acceleration is negative when it's slowing.

Answer (score 0):

The question tells you that the speed is decreasing. It is NOT constant.  For the speed to decrease, there has to be a force, and hence an acceleration, acting opposite to the initial direction of motion.  This decrease in speed required a -ve acceleration.

The question also says that the train turns round a circular bend. The centripetal force required to keep the train moving along a circular turn will be towards the centre of the circle, which will have a component opposite to the initial direction of motion (-ve acceleration) and another component which is perpendicular to the initial direction of motion (neither +ve nor -ve since perpendicular to initial motion).

Therefore, the net acceleration should have a negative sign.